# Returning and empty array

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have an equation which I want to perform for every element (e0) in the array called 'energy'. However each calculation requires looping over a set of values (i) in the range defined. When I try putting one loop inside the other it returns an empty array whereas I  want an array the same size as the energy array.

```
fp1 = []
for e0 in energy:
    for i in range(elow, ehigh, stepsize):
        fp1 = np.append(fp1, np.cumsum((2 / np.pi) * ((mu(element, e0) * i / ((e0 * e0)-)(i * i)))) * 2)
```

Relatively new to all this so assume I'm completely overlooking something.
Using Python 2.7 for this.

Cheers

Comment: What is the value of elow, ehigh, stepsize ? This would only generate a [] list if elow >= eghigh.

Comment: Can you confirm you are using Numpy here ? Because append returns an array for numpy arrays, and None for Python lists.

Comment: Are you sure about your code, cause it doesn't even run for me. Particularly: ((e0 * e0)-) seems pretty much a syntax error.

Comment: `fp1 = np.append()`?  What causes you to think that `list.append()` returns a value?

Comment: Please clearly define what you mean by "returns an empty array"?  There's no `return` and this isn't a function definition.

Comment: Man, if you don't answer to comments, nobody is going to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the situation in which a empty list shouldn't happen. But neigthe should what you expect, if what you said in your comment is true. For example:

```
 elow = 2
 ehigh = 900
 stepsize = 2
 fp1 = []
 energy = [1, 2, 3]
 for e0 in energy:
     for i in range(elow, ehigh, stepsize):
          fp1 = numpy.append(fp1, 15)

 fp1
 array([ 15.,  15.,  15., ...,  15.,  15.,  15.])
 len(fp1)
 1347
```

As you can see you won't get an array the same length of energy. This is because `range(2, 900, 2)` generated a list starting from 2 -> 898 (449 elements). This is generated for each element in energy and the result of your calculation will be appended to fp1 thus you should get a 449 * 3 = 1347 elements as result.

I can't really see any situation that you would get an empty list as result other than:

```
elow >= ehigh

energy = []

stepsize < 0
```

So my advice would be to do a print/debug of all these values right before the loops, and maybe try to better explain what you want to achieve because like I said, even if this would work you won't get an output of the same length as `energy` but rather of `length = len(energy) * 449`